# Finding the value of $\arctan(\frac32) - \arctan(\frac23) + \arctan(\frac25) + \arctan(\frac{1}{99})$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $$\arctan\left(\frac32\right) - \arctan\left(\frac23\right) + \arctan\left(\frac25\right) + \arctan\left(\frac{1}{99}\right).$$

---

My first thought upon seeing this problem was to use complex numbers, but I'm not sure which formulas I should apply here. Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: You can use $$\arctan A \pm \arctan B = \arctan\left(\frac{A\pm B}{1\mp AB}\right)$$ This is just the tangent angle addition formula, but with $A =\tan a $ and $B=\tan b$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Actually that's not quite true.  It's true that $\tan(\arctan A \pm \arctan B) = (A \pm B)/(1 \mp AB)$, but $\arctan A \pm \arctan B$ is not necessarily in the correct interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ to make it an arctan.

Comment: The following seems related to the discussion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying @NinadMunshi's idea with @RobertIsrael-inspired caution, $\arctan\tfrac32-\arctan\tfrac23=\arctan\tfrac{5}{12}$ so $\arctan\tfrac32-\arctan\tfrac23+\arctan\tfrac25=\arctan\tfrac{49}{50}$. We can then use$$\frac{\tfrac{n-1}{n}+\tfrac{1}{2n-1}}{1-\tfrac{n-1}{n}\tfrac{1}{2n-1}}=\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)+n}{n(2n-1)-(n-1)}=\frac{2n^2-2n+1}{2n^2-2n+1}=1$$to show the desired sum is $\arctan1=\tfrac{\pi}{4}$.